# How to speed up Python string matching code

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, dynamic-programming, lcs

I have this code which computes the [Longest Common Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) between random strings to see how accurately one can reconstruct an unknown region of the input. To get good statistics I need to iterate it many times but my current python implementation is far too slow.  Even using [pypy](http://pypy.org/) it currently takes 21 seconds to run once and I would ideally like to run it 100s of times.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random
import itertools
#test to see how many different unknowns are compatible with a set of LCS answers.
def lcs(x, y):
    n = len(x)
    m = len(y)
#    table is the dynamic programming table
    table = [list(itertools.repeat(0, n+1)) for _ in xrange(m+1)]
    for i in range(n+1):     # i=0,1,...,n
        for j in range(m+1):  # j=0,1,...,m
            if i == 0 or j == 0:
                table[i][j] = 0
            elif x[i-1] == y[j-1]:
                table[i][j] = table[i-1][j-1] + 1
            else:
                table[i][j] = max(table[i-1][j], table[i][j-1])

    # Now, table[n, m] is the length of LCS of x and y.
    return table[n][m]

def lcses(pattern, text):
    return [lcs(pattern, text[i:i+2*l]) for i in xrange(0,l)]

l = 15
#Create the pattern
pattern = [random.choice('01') for i in xrange(2*l)]

#create text start and end and unknown. 
start = [random.choice('01') for i in xrange(l)]
end = [random.choice('01') for i in xrange(l)]
unknown = [random.choice('01') for i in xrange(l)]

lcslist= lcses(pattern, start+unknown+end)

count = 0
for test in itertools.product('01',repeat = l):
    test=list(test)
    testlist = lcses(pattern, start+test+end)
    if (testlist == lcslist):
        count += 1

print count
```

I tried converting it to numpy but I must have done it badly as it actually ran more slowly.  Can this code be sped up a lot somehow?

**Update.** Following a comment below, it would be better if `lcses` used a recurrence directly which gave the LCS between `pattern` and all sublists of `text` of the same length. Is it possible to modify the classic dynamic programming LCS algorithm somehow to do this?

Comment: Use a C version and wrap it with ctypes or cython. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#C

Comment: That's a horrible solution to an algorithmic error.

Comment: @doukremt That sounds like a good idea although I have never done anything like that. Would you mind showing me how this would work in my case?

Comment: Regarding your update above: we don't write code for people on StackOverflow. Try implementing it and then open a new question if you can't get it right.

Comment: @msw I am not sure what the improved recurrence would be.

Comment: Well, whatever you do, [don't search StackOverflow for related answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+lcs?sort=frequent)!

Comment: @msw I know the recurrence for LCS and it's in my question. The problem is a sliding window version which is much less obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence table `table` is being recomputed 15 times on every call to `lcses()` when it is only dependent upon `m` and `n` where `m` has a maximum value of `2*l` and `n` is at most `3*l`.

If your program only computed table once, it would be dynamic programming which it is not currently. A Python idiom for this would be

```
table = None
def use_lcs_table(m, n, l):
    global table
    if table is None:
        table = lcs(2*l, 3*l)
    return table[m][n]
```

Except using an class instance would be cleaner and more extensible than a global table declaration. But this gives you an idea of why its taking so much time.

**Added in reply to comment:**

Dynamic Programming is an optimization that requires a trade-off of extra space for less time. In your example you appear to be doing a table pre-computation in `lcs()` but you build the whole list on every single call and then throw it away. I don't claim to understand the algorithm you are trying to implement, but the way you have it coded, it either:

1. Has no recurrence relation, thus no grounds for DP optimization, or
2. Has a recurrence relation, the implementation of which you bungled.

Comment: 'table' depends on the list 'pattern' and the particular sublist of 'text' it is being called with.  I am not sure what you meant.

Comment: You are right that a recurrence that found the LCS between pattern and every sublist of text of the same length directly would be better. Question edited.